# How can change the index of a document in mongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

I want to change the index of the  `symbol: "BTCH/USD"` TO  `symbol: "TSLA"`

Comment: You need to perform an _update_ operation on the collection's documents. You can use the [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method for that. Like in a JSON, MongoDB documents have _fields_ (or _properties_) -they are not referred as _indexes_. So, `symbol` is a field.